# Plot with 2 conditions on the y axis

Tags: r, data-visualization

First, I want to clarify this is a very basic question. I'm new using R (and programming in general).

I have a data.frame with 3 columns:

block, average condition 1, average condition 2.

The blocks run from 1 to 9 and the average are response times averaged across subjects. 
What I want to do is to plot both averages, one for each condition, while having in the x axis the progression of blocks. Therefore, I would expect to have one line for each condition running above the x axis.

My question is what plot function should I use. I've tried with nearly everyone but what I thought would serve (simply plotting a vector with two columns as entry, against the block column) doesn't work, it gives the error:

```
 'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

So I thought I should first plot only one condition and then somehow add the other line with a second command. I successfully plotted one condition as I wanted to:

```
plot(meanrts2[,3],meanrts2[,2],ylab="RT",xlab="block",type="l")
```

So here I'm choosing the 3rd and 2nd columns to do the plotting, but what I want is to have two columns running parallel, each one with different colors.

I tried abline, using the other columns I haven't plotted yet as an argument,  but I get the "invalid a=, b= specification"

Any suggestions are very welcome. Any other information I missed you can always ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

points(meanrts2[,3],meanrts2[,1],ylab="RT",xlab="block",type="l")

or

lines(meanrts2[,3],meanrts2[,1],ylab="RT",xlab="block")

would suffice... I guess

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed the lines() function worked for me, though in a slightly different way.

First I created my plot with column 1(y axis) and 3 (x axis):
plot(meanrts2[,3],meanrts2[,1],ylab="RT",xlab="block",type="l")
And then I just added the 2nd colum of my meanrts2 data.frame with this:
lines(meanrts2[,2])
And I got the plot I wanted with the two lines stemming from the y axis and going across the x axis.

Comment: Seems like a good question and a good answer.  I'm just confused because I've seen questions closed because they dealt only with how to program software and involved no statistical content.